# How to make Goldendict work with Shift+Right Click?

Tags: ubuntu, dictionary

I've recently installed GoldenDict on my Ubuntu. 
It's a pretty good piece of software, don't miss 
Babylon at all, it's just that I'm really use to 
the old Shift+right click shortcut, is there a way 
to make it work on GoldenDict?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about GoldenDict, as I am a Stardict user..

But if you mean the shortcut that you use to enable the text scanning and translating then why don't you use Stardict.  You can add all the dictionaries you need and it has a simple GUI and also has an option to set that shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

GoldenDict had 2 types of shortcut:

1. a shortcut to open its main window and enter the vocabulary manually.
2. a shortcut to show the meaning of a vocabulary in a text you're reading.

To set both shortcut keys you can go to edit > preferences > hotkeys

[image]

For using the second type, you should first copy the vocab to the clipboard, then press that shortcut.